# How can I register songs to my stereo?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have a stereo in Animal Crossing, but in order for it to play music I have to register songs

Where can I find these songs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy one of them each day at the ATM inside the resident services tent.

Choose the second option and you'll be able to buy some items with Bells. The available song changes each day.

If the new game follows the old games trend, there should be a couple of "hidden" songs, but I've not unlocked K.K. yet.

Comment: Make sure they're in your inventory (not storage) when you interact with your stereo, too!